# Laravel Login Authentication

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have two tables one is user and another one is role table.i want to check that login user has role status active also user status active i have tried

```
$user = User::whereHase('get_role', function($query){$query->where('status', 1);})
        where("email","=",$request->{$this->username()})
        ->where('password',"=",\Hash::make($request->password))->first();
```

But that is not work please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what was the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally got the solutions

$credentials = $this->credentials($request);

$login = $credentials[$this->username()];

\App\Models\User::select("users.id")->Join("roles","roles.id","=","users.role_id")->where("users.status",1)->where("roles.status",1)->where($this->username(), $login)->first()

Answer (score 3):

If this code is copied and pasted then you have at least one spelling error

```
$user = User::whereHase('
```

Change whereHase to whereHas, double check spellings and try again?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
 $user = User::whereHas('get_role', function($query){$query->where('status', 1);})
            ->where("email","=",$request->{$this->username()})
            ->where('password',"=",\Hash::make($request->password))->first();
```